# Why Do My Content Editor Web Parts Have "noindex" Class?

Tags: search, content-editor-web-part

When i create a content editor web part on a publishing page in SharePoint 2010, the following code is created:

```
<div WebPartID="151e7c56-689b-48ef-ab7e-7f8ed3958cb5" 
    HasPers="false" 
    id="WebPartWPQ1" 
    width="100%" 
    class="ms-WPBody noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace" 
    allowDelete="false" 
    style="" >
```

Why is the "noindex" CSS class present? Does this prevent the content from being indexed by a crawler? How can I remove this attribute?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be using content editor web parts in publishing pages for content, that's what the field controls are for in the page layout.

Comment: No argument there, @PirateEric. Nevertheless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a site setting.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-content-to-be-searchable-HA010379092.aspx#_Toc355013924

1. Navigate to the site for which you want to control the Web Parts in search results.
2. Click Site Actions, and then click Site Settings.
3. Under Site Administration, click Search and offline availability.
4. In the **Indexing ASPX Page Content** section, checked to **Always index all Web Parts on this site**